# Select values from a data frame based on a vector longer than object lenght

Tags: r

I encountered problem when extracting data from simple data frame.  Suppose following data frame:

```
> df  

 Currency  Rate
     AB       1
     CD       2
     EF       3
     GH       4
```

I want to extract rates for the following vector:

```
v <- c(EF, EF, GH, AB, CD, AB)
```

to do so I use following (which unfortunately does not work):

```
df[df[,1] %in% v, 2]
```

R returns:

```
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

But I am looking for this vector:

```
[1] "3" "3" "4" "1" "2" "1"
```

Any ideas, how I could  approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` which will cause the values to be repeated and in the order as in `v`:

```
df[match(v, df$Currency),2] 
#[1] 3 3 4 1 2 1
```